# proper way to store objects in a std vector

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, reference, new-operator

Let me explain my problem bit by bit.

This is a 2D game.

I have there simple class.

the first one is a Point class:

```
class Point {
public:
    double x;
    double y;

    Point(double x, double y)
    {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
    };
};
```

The second one is a class indicating a Edge :

```
class Edge {
public:
    Point startPoint;
    Point endPoint;

    Edge(Point startPoint, Point endPoint)
    {
        this->startPoint = startPoint;
        this->endPoint = endPoint;
    };
};
```

And then a class indicating a angle point:

```
class AnglePoint {
public:
    Point point;
    Edge prevEdge;
    Edge nextEdge;

    AnglePoint(Point point,
               Edge prevEdge,
               Edge nextEdge)
    {
        this->point = point;
        this->prevEdge = prevEdge;
        this->nextEdge = nextEdge;
    };
};
```

Then I have a std::vector to store the Edge objects I generated:

```
std::vector<std::vector<Edge>> polyEdgeArray;
```

And Here is how I initialize the `polyEdgeArray`:

```
polyEdgeArray.clear();
for (int i = 0; i < N; i ++) {
    std::vector<Edge> edgeArray;
    for (int j = 0; j < M; j ++) {
        Point s = Point(x, x);
        Point e = Point(x, x);
        edgeArray.push_back(Edge(s, e));
    }
    polyEdgeArray.push_back(edgeArray);
}
```

And I have another vector to hold all the AnglePoint objects:

```
std::vector<AnglePoint> anglePointArray;
```

And here is how I initialize the `anglePointArray`:

```
for (int i = 0, l = (int)polyEdgeArray.size(); i < l; i ++) {
    std::vector<Edge> edgeArray = polyEdgeArray[i];

    for (int j = 0, ll = (int)edgeArray.size(); j < ll; j ++) {
        Edge edge = edgeArray[j];
        Edge preEdge = (j == 0 ? edgeArray[ll - 1] : edgeArray[j - 1]);
        Edge nextEdge = (j == ll - 1 ? edgeArray[0] : edgeArray[j + 1]);
        addEndPointAnglePoint(edge.startPoint, edge, preEdge, nextEdge);
    }
}

void addEndPointAnglePoint(Point& point,
                           Edge& edge,
                           Edge& prevEdge,
                           Edge& nextEdge)
{
    AnglePoint anglePoint = AnglePoint(point, prevEdge, nextEdge);
    anglePointArray.push_back(anglePoint);
}
```

And then, here is the background of my game, the number of the `polyEdgeArray` and `anglePointArray` will be quite large, say 100000.

And, the `polyEdgeArray` and `anglePointArray` will be regenerated / recalculated per frame.

The code above works fine in my game but I am not sure if they are efficient enough.

Based on the information above I have several questions here:

a. For the class Edge, the params in construct is :

```
Point xxx
```

will it be better if I change it to :

```
Point* xxx or `Point& xxx`
```

b. Similarly about the `std::vector<Edge>`, should I change it to:

```
std::vector<Edge*>
```

c. In my case, which way is the better solution -- to save all the objects without the `new` operator or with the `new` operator as pointer.

Any advice will be appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: "The code above works fine in my game but I am not sure if they are efficient enough."  Then benchmark it.   Dont optimize working code until you've identified that it is too slow and if so, what part of it is too slow and how much faster it needs to be.  If you guess at what to optimize, you'll waste your time in the wrong places.  First focus on "does it work".  Who knows - you might end up throwing all this code out for another approach regardless of how fast it is.

Answer (score 1):

Before you go trying to optimise code because "not sure if they are efficient enough", do measurement to be sure there is a confirmed need.   Few things are worse drains on developer time than premature optimisation.

On a quick look though ....

Simplifying the initialisation of `polyEdgeArray` is simple, assuming you are actually initialising all the points for all the edges using the same value of `x`.

```
Point p(x,x);
std::vector<std::vector<Edge>> polyEdgeArray(N, std::vector<Edge>(M, Edge(p,p)));
```

will do exactly the same thing.

If your code is different (e.g. `x` is not fixed throughout your loops) however, there are a number of algorithms (in standard header `<algorithm>`) for initialising a range, or setting the value for all elements in a range using a function.   These algorithms are templated, so "value" can mean "instance of appropriate class".

Although I haven't checked if standard algorithms will be usable for initialising your `anglePointArray`, I suggest you do.

At worst, using standard algorithms - if they are applicable, of course - will make your code easier to understand, therefore easier to get right, and easier to maintain.   And there is a fair chance that implementers of the standard library will do a better job of optimising the standard algorithms than you'll be able to achieve in your code to do the same thing.